# Sum Column, but only Filtered Rows

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2003

I have a large flat file of a bunch of ungrouped primary key values.

I want to filter on a key and populate cell A1 with the value selected from the dropdown list.

In the end, I want to see a sum of each primary key's associated value in column D & G after filtering on that primary key.

I'm using this function at the top of row D and G respectively:

```
=SUMIF(A:A,A1,D3:D12982)    
=SUMIF(A:A,A1,G3:G12982)
```

Does anyone know, through using a function, not a macro, how to populate a cell with a filter's selected value?

Sample data & solution:

```
                             D                        G

                             7                        6
  id      class   trnsfr  reg_hrs   crs_no    sec  crs_hrs
6181191      BT     R        4      INIS210    1      3
6181191      ED     G        3      COMS223    4      3
```

Answer (score 3):

The **SUBTOTAL** function should give you what you need.

Put a formula similar to this in cell A1:

```
=SUBTOTAL(9,A3:A12982)
```

The function number of 4 in the **SUBTOTAL** function tells it to use the **MAX** function.

This works because unlike the **MAX** function, the **SUBTOTAL** function ignores any rows that are not displayed in the result set of a filter.

Comment: interesting... but it gives me 6 as the result... i am looking for the sum, not the max... you know what number 1-11 that is? im going to google it now

Comment: edit your answer to 9 so i can credit you with the correct response! thanks, i never ran into this function and its usefulness is apparent to me now

Comment: Also, on the Data tab in Excel 2007 there is a Subtotal button which makes setting the formula up a little easier. Its been a while since I've used 2003 but something similar may exist in the menus.

Answer (score 1):

Try a SUM(IF( Array formula. They are more powerful.

Remember every time you edit an Array formula you must re-enter it with <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd> not just <kbd>ENTER</kbd>.

see: http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel/HA010872271033.aspx

Comment: I'd have to name all my ranges, no?  Either way, the real bite is a command I don't know that probably exists that equates to the filtered value of a drop down... Or a combination of cell properties that can be accessed via a built in function.  I'm going to keep looking for the answer, but thanks

Comment: You don't have to name your ranges with the Array formulas. When you say filter, do you mean an Advanced Data Filter in excel?

Answer (score 0):

```
=SUBTOTAL(109,D3:D12982)

Syntax

SUBTOTAL(function_num, ref1, ref2, ...)

> Function_num is the number 1 to 11 (includes hidden values) 
> or 101 to 111
> (ignores hidden values) that specifies
> which function to use in calculating
> subtotals within a list.


    Function_num 
(includes hidden values) 
    1 AVERAGE 
    2 COUNT 
    3 COUNTA 
    4 MAX 
    5 MIN 
    6 PRODUCT 
    7 STDEV 
    8 STDEVP 
    9 SUM 
    10 VAR 
    11 VARP 

Function_num 
(ignores hidden values) 
    101 AVERAGE 
    102 COUNT 
    103 COUNTA 
    104 MAX 
    105 MIN 
    106 PRODUCT 
    107 STDEV 
    108 STDEVP 
    109 SUM 
    110 VAR 
    111 VARP
```